# Detect index page on Shopware

Tags: shopware6

How can I render some html based on the fact whether the home (landing) page is shown in Shopware?

I tried with various smarty ifs, but none of them worked.

Javascript is not an option - it does look ugly if the layout gets a major change in $(document).ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think of is adding a Subscriber to the page load event and then adding a page extension with a specific variable that you will use  in the if statements of your Twig templates.

I am not sure what you mean by "index page" but I think you're trying to detect if the page is the homepage?

In this case you can check if the route is equal to the Shopware `frontend.home.page` route:

```php
$currentRoute = $request->attributes->get('_route');
$page->addExtension('isHome', $request->attributes->get('_route') == 'frontend.home.page');
```

Now it will be possible to check if the current page is the homepage in Twig by using:

```
{% if page.extensions.isHome %}
    // Do your stuff here
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively you can also access the request object in the template directly:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works already out of the box like this in Shopware 6.4.19:

```
{% if activeRoute == "frontend.home.page" %}
   {# Do your stuff here #}
{% endif %}
```